# Int to str on Python

Tags: python

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = input("Please enter your age: ")
print ("Hello, " + name + ", you are " + age * 7 + " Years old in Dog years.").
```

This is my code and this is what I get.

```
Please enter your name: paris
Please enter your age: 13
Hello, paris, you are 13131313131313 Years old in Dog years.
```

I want 13 x 7 not 13 7 times. Can someone please help me? thx

Comment: `age = int(input("..."))`?

Comment: Just a quick side note, if you don't covert a string to an int and use "* 7", it will repeat it seven times.  Covert like the previous two comments said and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

In python you can do this `str * 7` and as you can see it will repeat it 7 times.

For what you want you want to cast age to int `int(age)` or cast your input to only accept ints `age = int(input("enter age"))` Like in the comments say.

For future reference you can test the type of a variable using `type(<variable>)`

Edit...

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
print ("Hello, " + name + ", you are " , age * 7 , " Years old in Dog years.")
```

Comment: Can you please write out the full code?

Comment: What was not clear in my answer, that needed a full code paste? I'm curious for the next time I answer someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Multipling a string with a integer is repeating it multiple times. You have to convert `age` to a number before doing calculations:

```
print("Hello, {}, you are {} Years old in Dog years.".format(name, int(age) * 7)
```